# MailChimp GAS - invalid resource: blank email

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I'm writing a script that takes google sheet data and uploads my mailchimp subscriber data, where the edited cell values are sent over as updated merge tags. The original code came from [here](https://github.com/pratik0809/GSheetsToMailchimp/blob/master/GSheetsToMC.gs). I've got the script running successfully, accept for this one error:

`"Invalid Resource","status":400,"detail":"Blank email address"`

I understand the error according to the documentation in the mailchimp api documentation, but I'm not sure why it's not recognizing the subscriber data from the script:

```
var emHash = md5(em.toLowerCase()); //this is pulled from my md5 function

var payload =  JSON.stringify({ 
"status_if_new": "subscribed", 
"email_address": em,
"merge_fields": {
    "LEAD": lead,
    //rest of vars following same syntax
}
});

  var options = {
    "headers" : headers,
    "payload": payload,
    "method" : "put",
    "muteHttpExceptions" : true
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://us15.api.mailchimp.com/3.0' + '/lists/' + 'xxxxxxx' + '/members/' + emHash,options);

  Logger.log(response);
}
```

Last is the function triggered by editing so that changed values get sent over via the function above

```
function onEdit(e) {
var activeSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
var range = e.range;
var rowedited = range.getRowIndex();
  if (activeSheet.getName() !== "ATTENDANCE"){
      return;
      Logger.log("Oops :(");
  }
  else {
      var values = sheet.getRange(rowedited, 1, 1, 13).getValues()[0];

       var em = values[2];
       var lead = values[1];
       //remaining vars omitted for brevity     
      sendToMailChimp_(em,lead...[etc.]);
  }
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out - I pulled an amateur move and had the columns attributed to the wrong array element.... So yes, I started at 1 and not 0

*facepalm*

It is now working!